# R: get nearest air temperature measurement for given location/date

Tags: r, noaa

I have the `latitude`, `longitude` and a `date`.

Q: Is there an easy way to get the nearest `air_temperature` measurement from there?

```
data$air_temperature = fetch_nearest_parameter(latitude = lat, longitude = lon, date = mydate, parameter = "air_temperature")
```

A great helper function to solve that task would be: select the nearest station at lat/long that offers air_temperature at my given date.

This is my latest attempt (not really working) is the following.
Step 1: select the 50 nearest stations
Step 2: for all of them, try to grab the air_temperature at my given date.
Step 3: hope that there is at least 1 match and then use this one.
Issue with this approach: there never is a single match in Step 3.

```
lat_lon_df <- data.frame(id = c("1"),
                         latitude = c(-33.8675),
                         longitude = c(151.2070))


# fetch 50 nearest stations
nearby_stations <- meteo_nearby_stations(lat_lon_df = lat_lon_df, limit=50,  var = c("TMAX"), 
                                          station_data = station_data, year_min=2000, year_max=2017)
ns <- do.call(rbind, lapply(nearby_stations, data.frame, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

mydate = 20160503
# check all 50 stations for air_temperature at my given date
# the column 'xxx' always ends up being filled 100 % with NAs
ns$xxx = lapply(ns$id, function(x) { return(tryCatch(coops_search(station_name = x, begin_date=mydate, end_date=mydate, product="air_temperature"), error=function(e) NA)) })
```

Comment: If you show the output after `Step 1`, we might be able to help you...

Comment: I also recommend 1) filtering your data for *only* stations with air_temperature on your given date, then 2) select closest one by distance.